# Como puedo forzar la instalación de un apk que ya esta instalada? error: "Existe un conflicto entre el paquete y otro paquete con el mismo nombre"

Tags: java, android-studio

Para que se entienda mejor, estoy instalando un apk desde otra apk ya instalada, pero al iniciar la instalación me dice "Existe un conflicto entre el paquete y otro paquete con el mismo nombre", así que intento que el apk se fuerce o se reinstale por la nueva versión que estoy intentando instalar.
Este el código que utilizo

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(appObjectInstall);

            String app = jsonObject.get("name").toString() + jsonObject.get("versionname").toString() + jsonObject.get("signature").toString();
            Log.e("name:", app);
            File downloads = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app/files/Download/fetch/");

            File file1 = new File(downloads + "//" + app + ".apk");//downloads.listFiles()[0];
            Uri contentUri1 = getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file1);

            // Intent to open apk
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, contentUri1);
            intent.setDataAndType(contentUri1, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error:

"Existe un conflicto entre el paquete y otro paquete con el mismo nombre"

Se debe a dos posibles razones:

- **El .APK instalado no está firmado con el mismo certificado del .APK que intentas instalar. Ambos .APK deben firmarse con el mismo certificado.**
- **El .APK que deseas instalar tiene un `versionCode` menor o igual al .apk instalado. El nuevo .APK a instalar debe tener un `versionCode` mayor.**

Debes asegurar que firmar tu .APK a instalar sea firmado con el mismo certificado que el .APK instalado y su `versionCode` debe ser mayor al .APK instalado.

Comment: Gracias, si era la versionCode

Comment: Excelente, saludos!